# SVG элемент Path не видит градиент в горизонтальном положении

Tags: javascript, svg, path

Есть такой пример, чтобы долго не объяснять, меняйте последнюю координату и увидите что происходит.

Js, к данной проблеме не имеет ни какого отношения `(смотреть пример 2)`, функция которая меняет последнюю координату `path`, только для того, чтобы людям которые будут читать вопрос, было бы легко и быстро увидеть проблему.

Что касается замены `path` на `rect`, не получиться... Это малая часть большого сложного, где нельзя заменить `path` на `rect`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('.path').setAttribute('d', 'M5 250 495 ' + input.value);
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.querySelector('.path').setAttribute('d', 'M5 250 495 ' + input.value);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

div.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #10e7dd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

svg {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%"  y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00f" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      <path class="path"  stroke-width="100" stroke="url(#gradient)" fill="none" d="M5 250 495 250.1"/>
      
      </svg>
  <div>
    <input type="number" value="250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот как выглядит без JS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

div.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #10e7dd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <defs>
              <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%"  y2="0%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00f" />
              </linearGradient>
            </defs>
          <path class="path"  stroke-width="100" stroke="url(#gradient)" fill="none" d="M5 250 495 250"/>
          
          </svg>
</div>
```

Что это, баг?  Как это исправить?

Comment: В части SVG всё работает нормально.  Причину нужно искать в JS, что-то не так с присвоением значения для Path

Comment: Js я для наглядности написал... Без js тоже самое

Comment: а как должно выглядеть ...без js ?

Comment: @Air Удалил JS вот так выглядит и в FF и Chrome https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7I1O.png

Comment: @zhurof, благодарю, то что надо. напиши ответом... я его приму

Comment: @MaximLensky, Макс, у меня ни в одном браузере не работает, напиши ответом, покажи как это у тебя получается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть предположение, что высота элемента из горизонтальной линии равна нулю (обводка не влияет на размер элемента), а размеры градиента по умолчанию считается от размеров элемента (`objectBoundingBox`). Если добавить для градиента `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, то работает. 
Однако при этом стоит учитывать, что координаты градиента будут рассчитываться относительно системы координат всего SVG-элемента.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('.path').setAttribute('d', 'M5,250 495,' + input.value);
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.querySelector('.path').setAttribute('d', 'M5,250 495,' + input.value);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

div.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #10e7dd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

svg {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <defs>
              <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%"  y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00f" />
              </linearGradient>
            </defs>
          <path class="path"  stroke-width="100" stroke="url(#gradient)" fill="none" d="M5,250 495,250"/>
          
          </svg>
  <div>
    <input type="number" value="250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abzgrVX  работает же без `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` но если стереть `"M5 250 495 250.1"` единичку то не работает ..

Comment: @MaximLensky  Потому что в таком случае высота `.path` не равняется нулю и у градиента есть размеры для отрисовки при `objectBoundingBox` (значение по умолчанию). Думаю дело в этом.

Comment: С вертикальной линией кстати таже фигня

Comment: да точно ...проверил

Answer (score 2):

Заменил линию на прямоугольник. Может так надежней будет, в смысле применения градиентов, для вашего приложения.

*Изменение размеров градиентной полосы в зависимости от `input`*

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var rect = document.getElementById("path");

slider.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {

  var sliderValue = evt.target.value;
   rect.setAttribute("width", sliderValue);
   
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

div.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #10e7dd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

svg {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%"  y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00f" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      <!-- <path class="path"  stroke-width="100" stroke="url(#gradient)" fill="none" d="M5 250 495 250.1"/> -->
      <rect id="path" x="5" y="250" width="10" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" >
    
    </rect>
      </svg>
  <div>
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="10" step="1" max="490"  value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

*Анимация градиентной полосы*

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var anim = document.getElementById("anim");

slider.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {

  var sliderValue = evt.target.value;
  var currentTo = anim.getAttribute("to");
  anim.setAttribute("from", 10);
  anim.setAttribute("to", sliderValue);
  anim.beginElement();

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

div.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #10e7dd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

svg {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%"  y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00f" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      <!-- <path class="path"  stroke-width="100" stroke="url(#gradient)" fill="none" d="M5 250 495 250.1"/> -->
      <rect class="path" x="5" y="250" width="10" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" >
    <animate id="anim"
      attributeName="width"
     dur="1s"
       fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
      </svg>
  <div>
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" step="1" max="490"  value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alexandr_TT, благодарю, но это немного не то... Но имеет право на жизнь